# Angular.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn Angular.JS, so I wrote this simple code just to test it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Angular.JS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myapp.js"></script>
    <p>The sum of 5+10 is: {{5 + 10}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In the browser I'm supposed to see the following output: `The sum of 5+10 is: 15`, but I just see it as it is: `The sum of 5+10 is: {{5 + 10}}`. I tried it both in Chrome and FF, I tried to add the angular.js from Google CDN with `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>`, I tried to move the script between the `<head>` tags, but the outcome is always the same.

What am I doing wrong? Why don't I have the output correctly?

Comment: @IgorSemin It's currently an empty file, no code there.

Comment: <html ng-app> or look your code in myapp.js

Comment: I suggest you change the title of your question. Your question has nothing to do with whether Angular.js works. It has to do with you not understanding how Angular works.

Comment: @Igal then remove ng-app name, just <html ng-app> because angular wait initialization module. Or you can add to your myapp.js  below code var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

Comment: Did you initialize the app in `myapp.js`? `var app = angular.module('myapp', []);`

Comment: @IgorSemin Yup, that was my problem, didn't initialize it. Newbie to angular... Could you please post it as an answer so I could accept it? Thank you!

Comment: @Blazemonger Nop, dodn't initialize it... Now it worked. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove name initialization in html:

```
<html ng-app>
```

Or initialize module in your javascript file:

```
  var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);
```

Second way is better.

Comment: This answer is far from being helpful. It 's vague and lacks detail.

Comment: @Romario the all details already there are in the start question as my opinion. 1 html file + 1 js file, I think my answer is quite enough for that. It is Angular 1st version, and I don't think that it is an actual answer for the new versions of angular.

Answer (score 4):

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
```

When you specify a name for ng-app, it's expecting to find a user-created module with that name. If you're truly just wanting your example to work, you can simply remove the `="myapp"` and you'll be all set.

```
<html ng-app>
```

If you want to keep your "myapp" name, add this script block after you load angular.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('myapp', []);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use "ng-app":

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app>
  {{ 5 + 10 }}
 </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fovjo6u0/).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

You need to instanciate the module `myapp` you are using here

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
```

with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
</script>
```

The final html is like this:

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Angular.JS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myapp.js"></script>
    <p>The sum of 5+10 is: {{5 + 10}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```